# How to check spring boot version compatibilty with spring data cosmos db?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm struggling to get cosmos db up and running after upgrading spring boot to 2.3.3.

Is there a compatibility chart please ?

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos has support for Spring 2.3.x. There is a helpful getting started guide on the Spring data readme on GitHub that may point to your issue.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/cosmos/azure-spring-data-cosmos